# Which resource should I use to keep my API RESTFul?

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-url, restful-architecture

I'm building an API to allow the client of the API to send notifications to remind a user to update an Order status. So far, there are two notifications:

- when the user hasn't marked the order as received;
- when the user hasn't marked the order as done.

I want to build this API to make it simple to extend to other notifications related to the order, but keep a simple URI for the clients of this API.
How can I define my resources in order to keep my API RESTFul?

I was thinking about having one of these structures:

*Option 1*:

```
POST: /api/ordernotification/receive/{id}
POST: /api/ordernotification/complete/{id}
```

*Option 2 (omit the status from the resource and post it instead)*:

```
POST: /api/ordernotification/?id={id}&statusID={statusID}
```

**EDIT**

*Option 2.1 (keeping an articulated URI, as suggested by @Jazimov)*:

```
POST: /api/ordernotification/{statusID}/{id}.
```

Which option is more appropriate? Is there any advantage that one option has over the other? Or are there any other option I haven't thought of?

Comment: You could use: /api/ordernotification/{statusID}/{id}. This is RESTful because you're working with an articulated URI and it is clear that you're working with the ordernotification function--let the routing take it from there. You also will have flexibility to add statuses as you see fit.

Comment: Perhaps option 3: `PATCH /api/order/{id}` with `{status:"received"}`. ([reference](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/))

Comment: @Kenney I think PATCH would be useful if I wanted to update the status of the order. In my example, I just want to send a notification telling a user to do so. The resource "order" would remain unchanged.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry, I misunderstood! Do those notifications result in emails being sent, for intance? If they just appear on a website dashboard I'd take a different approach.

Comment: @Kenney No worries. Yes, for now it results in emails being sent and we might use SignalR in the near future.

Comment: @Jazimov One disadvantage I see in options 2 and 2.1(your suggestion) is that the client of the API needs to get the order status list beforehand, when he might be interested in sending notifications only for "complete" status, in option 1 it would be very clear for the clients of the API. As a developer calling this API, I'd find easier a more verbose URI (option 1).

Comment: REST is not about which URLs you use. It's about navigating through the state of your application using hyperlinks.

In other words: make sure that your order resource links to the aforementioned resources. Then, the client does not need to know how to 'calculate' this link himself and you're free to change it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something along these lines

```
POST /api/order/1234/notifications/not-received
POST /api/order/1234/notifications/not-completed
```

Which can later be accessed via

```
GET /api/order/1234/notifications/not-received
GET /api/order/1234/notifications/not-completed
```

Or

```
GET /api/order/1234/notification/8899
```

There's no real limitation on how semantically rich a URI can be, so you might as well take advantage of that and be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have two types of `ordernotifications`: those for notifying `receive` and those for notifying `complete`. If those are two separate data models then I think nesting them is a good idea (i.e. a table called `ReceiveOrderNotification` and `CompleteOrderNotification`). If that's the case then you may want to expose two different endpoints entirely, such as `POST /api/receiveordernotification` and `POST /api/completeordernotification`.

But I don't think that's the best you can do, given so many overlapping similarities there probably are between order notifications. Now, option 2 is more like a `GET`, since you're using query parameters, so with your first option let's collapse them into this:

```
POST: /api/ordernotification/
```

and then pass it some JSON data to create the notifications

```
{
    "orderId": "orderId",
    "userId": "userId",
    "prompt": "not marked received/not marked done"
}
```

I also removed the `/{id}` because when you `POST` you create a brand new thing and the id has not been created yet, usually. Even if the client is creating an `id` and sending it to the API it is a good practice to leave it open so your API can handle creating a new, unique resource in its own way.

This is RESTful is because a `POST` creates a resource `ordernotification` with certain data points. Your first option made actions a resource in themselves but that's probably not represented in any data model in your backend. To be as RESTful as possible, your API endpoints should represent the database domains (tables, collections, etc). Then you let your controllers choose what service methods to use given the data sent in the request. Otherwise REST endpoints expose all the logic up front and get to be a long list of unmaintainable endpoints.

Comment: The only problem I see in specifying the status in the request, is that the client of the API needs to know which status to send, so I'll have to expose my OrderStatus API when they might only be interested in sending notifications for 1 status, say Complete. The POST /api/completeordernotification would be simpler and more meaningful, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think, to update status of already inserted records, your endpoint should be PUT instead of POST.

You can use

```
PUT: /api/ordernotification/:id/status/
```

with clients json data

```
 {
     "status": "your_status"
 }
```

according to request data, endpoint should update the record.

Comment: I don't want to update the order status. This API is to notify the user responsible for doing that action. So in this case the resource would be the order notification, not the order itself.

Comment: Ok, then I think your second option is better.